# Apple login in django rest framework with allauth and rest-auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I have implemented Apple login in django with allauth and rest-auth. I implemented same way as Google login which worked perfectly.

**views.py**

```
class AppleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = AppleOAuth2Adapter
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("auth/apple/", AppleLogin.as_view(), name="apple-login"),
]
```

**pip versions**

```
Django==2.2.17
django-allauth==0.43.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.3
djangorestframework==3.8.2
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
```

When I test as below I'm getting `KeyError: 'id_token'` and this is where error comes from: https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/providers/apple/views.py#L92

I have no idea how to fix this error.

Thank you for your help !

```
curl -X POST 'https://.../auth/apple/' \
              -d 'access_token=AUTHENTICATION_CODE'

or

curl -X POST 'https://.../auth/apple/' \
              -d 'id_token=ID_TOKEN'   \
              -d 'access_token=AUTHENTICATION_CODE'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this custom serializerClass.
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/pull/2424#issuecomment-651913243

It seems that the problem is in django-rest-auth
Your authentication view should look like this

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.apple.views import AppleOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.apple.client import AppleOAuth2Client
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView

class AppleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = AppleOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = 'https://anycallbackurlhere'
    client_class = AppleOAuth2Client
    serializer_class = CustomAppleSocialLoginSerializer
```

The only change in the SerializerClass is in the `validate` function so you can just override that method

```
from rest_auth.registration.serializers import SocialLoginSerializer

class CustomAppleSocialLoginSerializer(SocialLoginSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        .... #copy the method from the link above
```

Comment: @Ben and @Jonabc7 hello I have gone through this method but I am getting error ` from allauth.socialaccount.providers.Apple.views import AppleOAuth2Adapter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.Apple'`

Comment: @Kwall You need to update django-allauth to 0.43.0 or higher. Apple provider has been added in version 0.43.0. You can check release notes here: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release-notes.html#id2

Comment: @Ben Yeah It's working now, thank you very much

Comment: I tried the same way but ain't getting redirected on callback_url.