# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.Apple'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have gone through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65566226/11360069) to implement login with apple. When I used below code

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.apple.views import AppleOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.apple.client import AppleOAuth2Client
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView

class AppleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = AppleOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = 'https://anycallbackurlhere'
    client_class = AppleOAuth2Client
    serializer_class = CustomAppleSocialLoginSerializer
```

the I am getting this error

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.Apple.views import AppleOAuth2Adapter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.Apple'
```

Where I did wrong?
I am using [this](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#django) and [this](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#apple) packages.

Comment: Is `allauth.socialaccount.providers.apple` included in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: @HimanshuPatel Yes it's there.

Comment: @HimanshuPatel I have solved this by updating version from django-allauth==0.42.0 to django-allauth==0.43.0 . and it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by updating version from django-allauth==0.42.0 to django-allauth==0.43.0 . and it is fixed now